# How to group rows in SQL by earliest date when are there are multiple rows with earliest date?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to come up with a query that will return the aggregate data for the earliest orders the customers have placed. What I cannot quite wrap my head around is how to construct this query when there are multiple orders placed on the same day for the earliest purchase date for customer 2.

```
                                 customers
```

| id | name | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sam | 2019-07-12 |
| 2 | Jimmy | 2019-01-22 |

```
                                   items
```

| id | name | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Watch | 200 |
| 2 | Belt | 75 |
| 3 | Wallet | 150 |

```
                                  orders
```

| id | customer_id | item_id | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 2018-08-01 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 2018-08-11 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | 2019-01-22 |
| 4 | 2 | 3 | 2019-01-22 |
| 5 | 2 | 2 | 2019-03-03 |

```
                             expected query
```

| customer_id | name | first_purchase_date | n_items | total_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sam | 2018-08-01 | 1 | 200 |
| 2 | Jimmy | 2019-01-22 | 2 | 350 |

I currently have the following query set up, but this query is grouping by the customer_id such that the total number of items and total price do not reflect the earliest orders.

```sql
SELECT 
    orders.customer_id, 
    customers.name AS name, 
    MIN(orders.created_at) AS first_purchase_date,
    COUNT(*) as n_items,
    SUM(items.price) as total_price
FROM orders
INNER JOIN customers
    ON orders.customer_id = customers.id
INNER JOIN items
    ON orders.item_id = items.id
GROUP BY
    customers.id
```

```
         my incorrect query
```

| customer_id | name | first_purchase_date | n_items | total_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sam | 2018-08-01 | 2 | 275 |
| 2 | Jimmy | 2019-01-22 | 3 | 425 |

Comment: Please would you read, [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)
and amend your question accordingly.

Comment: Please don't link to images. Add all relevant information directly to your question, preferably as editable text

Answer (score 0):

I recreated the tables in a SQL Server environment but this should help...I hope as it gives you the query result you're looking for.  The data is exactly the same but I'm using temporary tables so hence the # prefixes.

```
SELECT 
    #orders.customer_id, 
    #customer.name AS name, 
    #orders.created_at as first_purchase_date,
   --MIN(#orders.created_at) AS first_purchase_date,
   COUNT(*) as n_items,
   SUM(#items.price) as total_price
FROM #orders
    INNER JOIN #customer
ON #orders.customer_id = #customer.id
INNER JOIN #items
ON #orders.item_id = #items.id
inner join 
(
    select customer_id, name, MIN(first_purchase_date) as 
    first_purchase_date
    from 
    (
        SELECT 
            #orders.customer_id, 
            #customer.name AS name, 
            #orders.created_at as first_purchase_date,
            --MIN(#orders.created_at) AS first_purchase_date,
            COUNT(*) as n_items,
            SUM(#items.price) as total_price
        FROM #orders
        INNER JOIN #customer
            ON #orders.customer_id = #customer.id
        INNER JOIN #items
            ON #orders.item_id = #items.id
            group by #orders.customer_id,#customer.name, #orders.created_at
    )base
    group by customer_id, name
) firstorders
on 
#customer.id = firstorders.customer_id
and
#customer.name = firstorders.name
and
#orders.created_at = firstorders.first_purchase_date
group by 
#orders.customer_id,#customer.name, #orders.created_at
```